# How to scale a tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, scaling

I am using

```
 \documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

   \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\def\scl{0.6}%scaling factor of the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
   rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25)
    rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  % Screen, centered around the origin then shifted for easy plotting
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=8cm,samples=150]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-4.3)
      rectangle (5.3,4.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-4.0) rectangle (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-4.0) grid (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-4)--(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-3.8,-3.6,...,3.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower left panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (0.6,0.5) rectangle (13.5,3.0);
  \path (0.8,0.9) node[scale=\scl,right]{$\mathbf{TeXtronics\,1 - v.1.01}$};
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[thick] (16.6,1.5) --(17,1.5)--(17,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (16.7,1.0)--(17.3,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (16.8,0.85)--(17.2,0.85);
  \draw[thick] (16.9,0.70)--(17.1,0.70);
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % CH II
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \draw[thick] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[thick] (24.2,1.5) --(23.7,1.5)--(23.7,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (23.4,1.0)--(24.0,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (23.5,0.85)--(23.9,0.85);
  \draw[thick] (23.6,0.70)--(23.8,0.70);
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % Y-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
 \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2)
      rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]
      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
     \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
   \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,
      255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,
      108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output I get is something like that

[image]

I also tried to play with variable scl but the output is really ugly...

[image]

[image]

I also tried to put it in a `figure` enviroment with `includegraphics[scale=...]{begin{tikzpicture}...{\end{tikzpicture}}` but it isn't working...

Any ideas guys on how to scale it down and keep it pretty at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

Separating each diagram from the main input file will be a way to reduce complexity.

### Diagram

Compile the diagram `osci.tex` with pdflatex to get `osci.pdf`

```
% this file name is osci.tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary
{
    calc,
    fadings,
    shadings,
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}

\begin{document}
\def\scl{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
   rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25)
    rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  % Screen, centered around the origin then shifted for easy plotting
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=8cm,samples=150]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-4.3)
      rectangle (5.3,4.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-4.0) rectangle (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-4.0) grid (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-4)--(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-3.8,-3.6,...,3.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower left panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (0.6,0.5) rectangle (13.5,3.0);
  \path (0.8,0.9) node[scale=\scl,right]{$\mathbf{TeXtronics\,1 - v.1.01}$};
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[thick] (16.6,1.5) --(17,1.5)--(17,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (16.7,1.0)--(17.3,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (16.8,0.85)--(17.2,0.85);
  \draw[thick] (16.9,0.70)--(17.1,0.70);
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % CH II
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \draw[thick] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[thick] (24.2,1.5) --(23.7,1.5)--(23.7,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (23.4,1.0)--(24.0,1.0);
  \draw[thick] (23.5,0.85)--(23.9,0.85);
  \draw[thick] (23.6,0.70)--(23.8,0.70);
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % Y-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
 \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2)
      rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]
      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
     \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
   \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,
      255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,
      108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Main input file

Also compile the main input file with pdflatex. This main  input file imports `osci.pdf`. Adjust the scaling until it conforms to your need.

```
% this file name is main.tex
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{osci}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually I wanted do input it directly and not as an external image-there a quality loss there. If I remove `thick lines` and `round corners` it's getting better but not perfect. Let alone having to deal with this ugly spacing-see next answer...

Comment: @Thanos: There is no quality loss if you use PDF images.

Comment: All right you maybe right. But how am I going to fix this ugly spacing?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried putting the `tikzpicture` inside a `\resizebox`? I've tried and the results look good to me.

What I'm suggesting is doing something like:

```
\resizebox{1cm}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % TikZ picture code here
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! The thing is that I can resize it[thank you for that] but spacing issue still remains...

Answer (score 2):

I found a way but it is not perfect...

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,draw=black},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black},
  axes/.style={}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,draw=black](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black](0.25,0.25)
    rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  % Screen, centered around the origin then shifted for easy plotting
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=8cm,samples=150]
    \fill[black!60!,draw=black](-5.3,-4.3)
      rectangle (5.3,4.3);
   \fill[screen] (-5.0,-4.0) rectangle (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-4.0) grid (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-4)--(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-3.8,-3.6,...,3.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (3,0);
  \fill[black!70!,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (3,0);
   % Lower left panel
   \fill[controlpanels] (0.6,0.5) rectangle (13.5,3.0);
  \path (0.8,0.9) node[scale=\scl,right]{$\mathbf{TeXtronics\,1 - v.1.01}$};
  % Lower right panel
 \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
    \fill[gray,draw=black] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[] (16.6,1.5) --(17,1.5)--(17,1.0);
  \ draw[] (16.7,1.0)--(17.3,1.0);
 \ draw[] (16.8,0.85)--(17.2,0.85);
 \draw[] (16.9,0.70)--(17.1,0.70);
  \draw[] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  %CH II
  \fill[gray,draw=black] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \draw[] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[] (24.2,1.5) --(23.7,1.5)--(23.7,1.0);
  \draw[] (23.4,1.0)--(24.0,1.0);
  \draw[] (23.5,0.85)--(23.9,0.85);
  \draw[] (23.6,0.70)--(23.8,0.70);
      \draw[] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % Y-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,draw=black] (-2,-2)
      rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black]
      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,
      255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
  \draw[blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  \draw[blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,draw=black] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,
      108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Actually I removed `thick` lines and `rounded corners`. This is the output but it's not perfect...

[image]

Is there a way to do it with better spacing as a list item?

---

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item<2-> second item 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\uncover<2->{\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scope}%
\end{figure}}
\end{minipage}
```

With `columns`

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item<2-> second item 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}
\uncover<2->{\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scope}%
\end{figure}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Comment: I would use two minipages side by side, the left for the itemize list and the right for the image.

Comment: I tried with `minipage` and `columns` but I get a lot of errors. My compiler doesn't like that...

Comment: show what you did and we will/can help

Comment: I am editing my answer!

Answer (score 1):

delete the second line if it is running. I used the minipage example:

```
\listfiles
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%%%%% delete it later
 \documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
\def\scl{0.2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item<2-> second item 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\linewidth}
\raisebox
{-\height}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,draw=black},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black},
  axes/.style={}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,draw=black](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black](0.25,0.25)
    rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  % Screen, centered around the origin then shifted for easy plotting
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=8cm,samples=150]
    \fill[black!60!,draw=black](-5.3,-4.3)
      rectangle (5.3,4.3);
   \fill[screen] (-5.0,-4.0) rectangle (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-4.0) grid (5.0,4.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-4)--(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-3.8,-3.6,...,3.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (3,0);
  \fill[black!70!,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (3,0);
   % Lower left panel
   \fill[controlpanels] (0.6,0.5) rectangle (13.5,3.0);
  \path (0.8,0.9) node[scale=\scl,right]{$\mathbf{TeXtronics\,1 - v.1.01}$};
  % Lower right panel
 \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
    \fill[gray,draw=black] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (16.2,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[] (16.6,1.5) --(17,1.5)--(17,1.0);
  \ draw[] (16.7,1.0)--(17.3,1.0);
 \ draw[] (16.8,0.85)--(17.2,0.85);
 \draw[] (16.9,0.70)--(17.1,0.70);
  \draw[] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  %CH II
  \fill[gray,draw=black] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \draw[] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.4cm);
  \fill[black!60!] (24.6,1.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \draw[] (24.2,1.5) --(23.7,1.5)--(23.7,1.0);
  \draw[] (23.4,1.0)--(24.0,1.0);
  \draw[] (23.5,0.85)--(23.9,0.85);
  \draw[] (23.6,0.70)--(23.8,0.70);
      \draw[] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  % Y-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,draw=black] (-2,-2)
      rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black]
      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,
      255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (13.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
  \draw[blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  \draw[blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,draw=black] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,
      108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and effort!!! The thing is that  the image is suppossed to be quite small. So if I change `width=0.89\textwidth` for the list and `width=0.09\textwidth` for the image, the latter is printed out of the slide's range.

Comment: try `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

Comment: I forgot to mention...I also tried `linewidth` but it didn't work either... I also thought of playing with `\begin{picture}{0,0}...\end{picture}` but again I couldn't gat it to work.

Comment: sorry, but that does not help to say what you did wrong. Edit always your or my _complete_ example. Then I can help ...